# React Native WebView not opening link tel: on some Xiaomi phones

Tags: android, react-native, webview, xiaomi, tel

I have an Android app developed in React Native that is an WebView.

The site has an phone button with a `tel:123456789` uri that works very well in most of the devices tested.

It only does not open the dialer from the app on some Xiaomi phones. If I open the site in the smartphone browser, the button works well and open the dialer, but from the webview app it does not work.

App.js:

```
  const App = () => {
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = React.useState(false);
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  ...
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <WebView
          ref={ref}
          source={{uri: 'https://example.com/'}}
          geolocationEnabled={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={navState => {
            setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack);
          }}
         
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
};
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypackage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
          android:name=".SplashActivity"
          android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
             </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any update on it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add runtime permission and add this inside "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            ......
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"          />
            </intent-filter>
          
        
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).